# Extracting tuples from a list in Scala

Tags: list, scala, tuples, extract

I have this line of code:

```
for (validBooking <- validBookings){}
```

which always complains:

```
Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type A
```

The type for `validBookings` is `List[(Long, DateTime, DateTime)]`.

May I know what is wrong with my assignment for `validBookings`?

Comment: Is it possible that the wrapping function where the `for` loop placed, isn't returning anything and should return object with type `A` ?

Comment: Is this code block the last line in a some method which returns A?

Comment: I think the error didn't come from the line in your post. Can you post the code around this line ?

Comment: may it be that you missed a `yield` ? `for (validBooking <- validBookings) yield result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `yield` here otherwise the return type would be `Unit`:

```
for (validBooking <- validBookings) yield validBooking
```